# why php unlink() show no such file or directory?

Tags: php

i have a probelm where i want to update my image in database using unlink(). The error is **Warning: unlink(images/481933.jpg):** **No such file or directory**. I try search the solution but nothing can solve my problem. anyone can help me? thank you in advanced. this is my code:

```
$upload_dir='images/';

$imgExt=strtolower(pathinfo($images,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

$valid_extensions=array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'pdf');

$picProfile=rand(1000, 1000000).".".$imgExt;

unlink($upload_dir.$edit_row['prod_img']);

move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir, $upload_dir.$picProfile);

$stmt=$db_conn->prepare('UPDATE product SET prod_name=:prod_name, category=:category, 
prod_img=:prod_img, unit_price=:price, stock=:stock, min_limit=:min_limit, weight=:weight, 
description=:description, packaging=:packaging, size=:size, retail_price=:retail, agent_price=:agent 
WHERE prod_id=:prod_id');
```

Comment: Are you trying to delete a recently uploaded image? If so, PHP automatically deletes the temporary image after the request is completed.

Comment: Most obvious reason is that `images/481933.jpg` doesn't exist. The code you've shared gives no clue as to whether the file should exist or not. If you're trying to overwrite an old file, how do you know it always exists?